# Kotlin unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, build-error

At first - I've been googling to much and use all, what I am found.

My project level build.gradle contains this

at root of file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.2.31"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        .....
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        .....
    }
}
```

My module level build.gradle contains this

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "iam.thevoid.sudoku"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}


dependencies {
    ..........
    // kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    .........
}
```

but i still continue getting the errors during the build

```
e: \pages\BaseActivity.kt: (16, 9): Unresolved reference: window
e: \pages\GameActivity.kt: (37, 21): Unresolved reference: startActivity
e: \pages\MenuActivity.kt: (30, 21): Unresolved reference: startActivity
e: \util\FileUtil.kt: (19, 31): Unresolved reference: assets
e: \util\FileUtil.kt: (21, 51): Unresolved reference: it
e: \viewmodel\MenuViewModel.kt: (42, 70): Unresolved reference: finish
```

As you can see - there are simple references, as 'startActivity' or 'finish'. Why does kotlin can not resolve it?

I started get these errors when I've updated something i did not remember. Maybe it was a kotlin plugin version, may be there was an gradle or gradle plugin, but i try downgrade this plugins and not return project in working version.

Can you help?

Comment: Firstly, check your android dependencies in module level build.gradle. Have you updated build tools? Which build tools version do you have installed and which is declared in `android` block in build.gradle?

Comment: Open the mentioned files in Android Studio follow the red underlines. Are you extending AppCompatActivity? Did you forget to add dependency on support library?

Comment: @EugenPechanec all dependencies in project, activity is AppCompatActivity. Fun fact is the all this code works before i've updated gradle file, but when i tried to downgrade all - errors are not gone

Comment: @jelic98 I've added 'android' block in my Q. As you can see - build tools, sdk versions and other are the newest

Comment: where is the support library dependency?

Comment: @iamthevoid You should have mentioned that in the question. Why don't you start with *exactly* what you changed - state before and after - and we can move from there. This is 99% not related to Kotlin at all. Your BaseActivity cannot resolve a method of Activity because it extends *some class* (as far as its concerned). We know it extends AppCompatActivity/FragmentActivity but BaseActivity knows nothing. Its parent is not found on classpath.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help and spent time. I've found the solution. Described in question

Comment: @iamthevoid If you found a solution post it as an answer. You can answer your own questions. So the question doesn't show as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

I've found problem! 
There was dependency, which is break the build. In my case it was the

```
implementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.3.148'
```

I've added this for testing Exposed, but i did that at the same time when i updated the build.gradle file.

If you got same erros you can also check your dependencies. Probably one of them break the build.